# Where can I find ListView control styles?

Tags: c#, listview, interop

I spent a while searching the internet, but cannot seem to find a list of ListView styles or exstyles. I'm interested in finding out the value for:

LVS_EDITLABELS

as well as others. Is there any place where these are listed? I see a lot of examples online, but not list the values of the styles. They are simply called by name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It s defined in `CommCtrl.h` as

```
#define LVS_EDITLABELS  512
```

Answer (score 1):

The header files for the windows platform SDK define these values.  If you're using Visual Studio then you may already have a copy of the platform SDK installed on your machine; look for a folder named "PlatformSDK."  The ListView styles are defined in CommCtrl.h:

```
#define LVS_EDITLABELS          0x0200
```